# How do I test an async handler in @testing-library/react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, react-testing-library

I can not wrap my head around this but it's probably a simple one.

Let's say I have this:

```
   <MyComponent amazingAction={action}/>
   <MagicButton/>
```

So it's essentially a component with a handle and another component that when clicked will do an async action. Because of that async action, the handler in *MyComponent* will be triggered.

I essentially want to test that if I render both and trigger a click on the button, the handler will be called.

I tried this:

```
const maybeThisWorks = jest.fn();

const { getByText } = render(
      <MyComponent amazingAction={maybeThisWorks}/>
      <MagicButton title="My Button"/>
);

let button = getByText("My Button");
fireEvent.press(button);

expect(maybeThisWorks).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Try [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor). You'll need to add `async` to your test function.

Comment: nice one, it worked

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor). You'll need to change your test function to `async`.

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(maybeThisWorks).toHaveBeenCalled());
```